# Need assistance writing angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this code which repeats many times in my HTML:

```html
<div multi-select
     input-model="filters.REPLACEMENT_A" 
     button-label="name" 
     item-label="name" 
     tick-property="selected"
     default-label="REPLACEMENT_B"
></div>
```

The only parts which change are the two REPLACEMENT_ strings.  I'd thus like to make a directive which I would call like so:

```html
<myDirective model="regions" label="The label here"></myDirective>
```

I'm thinking that since this directive essentially returns yet another directive (the multi-select directive) I somehow have to compile/process it vs. just returning the simple string, right?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.  No clue if it's the "right" way.

```js
var filterDefinition = function ($compile) {
     return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var content = '<div multi-select button-label="name" item-label="name" tick-property="selected" group-property="group"';
            content += ' input-model="filters.' + attrs.filter + '"';
            content += ' default-label="' + attrs.label  + '"></div>';

            var jqLiteElem = angular.element(content);
            $compile(jqLiteElem)(scope);

            element.replaceWith(jqLiteElem);
        }
    };
};
```